# Calculating conditional costs

Tags: computer-science

In Visual Basic there is an example that tells me I have to calculate the cost of copies if a copy centre charges 5 cents per copy on the first 100 copies and three cents more for each additional copy after 100 copies, then displays the cost in a textbox.

This is what I have so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim firsthun As Double
        Dim plushun As Double
        If firsthun <= 100 Then '5 cents per copy'

        End If

        If plushun >= 100 Then 'add 3 cents more'

        End If
        TextBox2.Text =
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim copies As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim cost As Double = Nothing

    If copies <= 100 Then '5 cents per copy'
        cost = copies * 0.05
    ElseIf copies > 100 Then 'add 3 cents more'
        cost = 5 + (copies - 100) * 0.03 '5$ for the first 100, plus $0.03 for every copy after 100
    End If

    TextBox2.Text = Math.Round(cost, 2).ToString
End Sub
```

Here I have created a textbox `TextBox1` for the user to input how many copies they want. When they click `Button1`, it will calculate the value, and then output it to `TextBox2`, rounded to 2 decimal places.

Note that if the user inputs any value other than an integer into `TextBox1`, the program will crash as it will not be able to convert the value entered into an integer. You may want a Try/Catch statement, like so:

```
Dim copies As Integer

Try
    copies = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount!")
End Try
```

Hope this helps!